# WPF Checkbox vs BulletChrome

Tags: wpf, checkbox, treeviewitem

I have in my XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-5,0,0,0">
        <Border Name="SelectedBorder" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeViewItem}}" BorderThickness="0.5" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
------>             <CheckBox Margin="0,1,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsOn}"/>
                    <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="3,0,0,0" Source="{ Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter} }"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="3,1,0,0" Width ="150" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
......
```

This is used in a tree as nodes. 
In the tree, I handle `PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)` to [receive the click even if it happened on a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742666/wpf-clicking-on-a-datagrid-row-inside-a-treeview-does-not-trigger-treeview-sele).

```
    void TreeviewItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OriginalSource is System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)
        {
           ******* THIS NEVER HAPPENS
        }
```

When clicked on Image or TextBox on the treenode:
`sender` is TreeViewItem, `e.Source` is ContentPresenter , `e.OriginalSource` is Image or TextBox. This is fine.

However, if I click on CheckBox, the `e.OriginalSource is Microsoft.Windows.Themes.BulletChrome`.
I know this is somehow related to windows theme (PresentationFramework (""|"Aero"|"Royale"|"Luna").dll

1. But why is this, I want to work with my CheckBox here.
2. How can I get the CheckBox? (BulletChrome.TemplateParent??)
3. Can I rely on this, so when user clicks on CheckBox (even on a non-aero machine, like old windows, etc), it always will be BulletChrome?
4. Better to use? `if (e.OriginalSource is System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox || e.OriginalSource is Microsoft.Windows.Themes.BulletChrome)`
5. To call `e.OriginalSource is Microsoft.Windows.Themes.BulletChrome` I need a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero.dll or PresentationFramework.Royale.dll. Does it matter which one?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `Source` instead of `OriginalSource` (or even `sender` for that matter). [`OriginalSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx) is for *pure* hit-testing.

Comment: No, `sender = TreeViewItem` and `e.Source = ContentPresenter `. Updated my question with these details, please see. `e.OriginalSource` is proper for TextBlock or Image, but when CheckBox is clicked, OriginalSource is BulletChrome .